# Nothing written next to remote: in git

Tags: git, github

So I was working on a project, made changes in the file and did add (worked fine), git commit (worked fine). But when I did a git push this happened:

1) It didn't have anything written next to 'remote:'. It had only an empty line. No text, no information (not even error). So When I checked my github repo, these was a new commit but when I tried opening the commit it said error 404 no page found.

2) When cloning the repo same thing happens.

I have tried re installing git, but it did not work.

```
Cloning into 'server'...
remote:                                                                                                                                                                                                                remote:                                                                                                                                                                    remote: Enumerating objects: 4, done.
remote:                                                                         remote:                                                                         remote:                                                                         remote:                                                                         remote:                                                                         remote: Counting objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote:                                                                         remote:                                                                         remote:                                                                         remote:                                                                         remote:                                                                         remote: Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
remote: Total 1248385 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 1248381
Receiving objects: 100% (1248385/1248385), 716.65 MiB | 949.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (903057/903057), done.
Updating files: 100% (24572/24572), done.
```

Comment: Github is having some issues at the moment: https://www.githubstatus.com/

Comment: Your issue was probably just a temporary one because Github suffered some issues. Could you check your repo again now and check if you can open the commit's page?

Comment: @DelenaMalan I am able to open the commit page again. Thanks! But the empty line next to 'remote:' is still there

Answer (score 3):

Messages prefixed with `remote:` are messages that were emitted, not by *your* Git, but by the other Git your Git phoned up over the Internet.  Remember that `git fetch` and `git push` both work by having your Git call up some other Git.  Your Git has a little conversation of sorts with that other Git, in which your Git and their Git exchange commit and other related hash IDs so that whoever is sending (you, for `git push`; them, for `git fetch`) can send any commits and related objects that whoever is receiving *should* have, but doesn't.

This conversation deliberately leaves room for the other Git to send messages to your Git that your Git should present to you.  When that other Git *does* send messages, your Git shows them to you, adding the word `remote:` in front.

There's no easy way to tell what any given message means.  Some messages—such as `enumerating` and `counting` objects—actually come from Git helpers that the other Git has invoked; you see these same messages from your own Git at times.  But others may come from Git *hooks*.  Their Git—or whoever runs it—sets these up.  They can do anything.  Your Git has no control over them.<sup>1</sup>  If they emit weird random messages, you will see weird random messages, prefixed by the usual `remote:`.

In this case, it was probably the GitHub glitch.

---

<sup>1</sup>Due to popular demand, the Git folks actually *did* add the ability to set some control knobs on your side, that Git hooks on the *other* side *can* look at and use.  This is what the `--push-option` to `git push` is about.  These do not seem to be used very often in practice, though.  It's up to the other Git's hooks to explicitly check for, and use, any such options—by default they're completely ignored anyway.

Comment: It explains the ASCII art I occasionnally saw, either from public platforms (bitbucket in my case) or private ones. I guess the temptation was just too great...

Answer (score 2):

Copying @Delena's comment here so that we can link duplicates here:

> Github is having some issues at the moment: https://githubstatus.com
>
> Your issue was probably just a temporary one because Github suffered some issues. Could you check your repo again now and check if you can open the commit's page? – Delena Malan 2 hours ago

Answer (score 1):

This issue you're seeing is [a regression in Git 2.22.1 and 2.23.0](https://public-inbox.org/git/20190822171609.GA56720@syl.lan/T/#mfa8d299b414e06425b1e53f2fef38635a1571d5d) that causes extra whitespace to be delivered on terminals less than approximately 88 characters in width.  This affects folks who use an 80-character terminal, but not much wider terminals, which is probably why this hadn't been noticed earlier.

GitHub had rolled that version out, but has reverted the affected patches that caused the issue until a permanent solution has been devised.  So this issue should no longer be occurring.